# Add files to existing android app with no stores involved

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I have very little experience in app development. I have to update an existing music app (written in Phonegap/Cordova).

The update should add new songs (MP3) and update an existing JS file.

The app is not installed via the Store, we installed it manually. So no stores are involved.

What's the best way to add these MP3 files and update the JS file?

Comment: i think you should add mp3 files and rebuild it with phonegap build

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan Ok. In what kind of format?  A new APK to install? Does that APK needs to replace the current app? Or is there a possibility that the APK just adds some files?

Comment: no you have to replace your apk from new apk

Comment: the simple way is update your files and generate new apk and then install new apk in your mobile after uninstalling old app